# How to remove <pre> tag in wp shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a shortcode that will show the most recent post. I have used the following code for the shortcode

```
 function my_recent_posts_shortcode( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        'limit' => 5 
        ), $atts,'recent-posts' ) );

$q = new WP_Query( 
 array('posts_per_page'=>'.$limit.','post_type'=>'post')
);


$list = '';
while($q->have_posts()):$q->the_post();
    $list .= '<div class="post">
        <img class="img_border img_border_b img_fl" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/blog/01.jpg" alt="Post Image 1" />
        <div class="post_content">
            <h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>

            '.the_content().'
            <a class="more" href="fullpost.html">More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>';

endwhile;

wp_reset_query();

return $list;
}

add_shortcode( 'recent-posts', 'my_recent_posts_shortcode' );
```

After that i have created a page and i select the default page template for that? This is my page.php template loop

```
<div id="templatemo_content" class="left">
        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?Php the_content();?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>    
            <?php endif; ?> 




    </div>
```

Following is my shortcode

```
  [recent-posts limit="3"]
```

But when i see the result, it show a 'pre' tag.

Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Is it wrapping the output of your shortcode in `<pre>` tags or is it _only_ outputting a `<pre>` tag?

Comment: It is wrapping the output

Comment: Also all post content show first. then show post title and image

Comment: When I use your shortcode function on my WordPress installation it does not output with `<pre>` tags. Do other shortcodes get wrapped in `<pre>` tags as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the_content() is outputing your content, please replace it with `apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content())` 
in your my_recent_posts_shortcode function, after replacing it will will work !!

Regards

Comment: it is solve the content problem. But content goes the div range. My content width is 500px. it takes the full page width and overlap in sideber

Comment: This is css problem, can you send me url? Or past here your css code for this blocks ?

Comment: It is on my localhost and it is ok in .html file. But problem when convert in wp. I think , it is for 'pre' tag

Comment: #templatemo_content {
    width: 500px; 
    }

Comment: ok if you are thinking that problem comes from <pre> tag add strip_tags(apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content()))

Comment: specify in strip_tags which tags you want to allow wp to add

Comment: I want to remove the 'pre' tag

Comment: ok please replace <pre> and </pre> with '', using str_replace or use preg_replace what is more comfortable for you :)

Comment: You should not have to remove the `<pre>` tags with any sort of replacement. Something is generating them when it shouldn't, so this doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Check the edit mode of the page in question where you fitted your shortcode.
If you use a wysiwyg editor and you are in "Visual" mode your shortcode may have the PRE wrapper. Check it in "Text" mode.

```
<pre>[Blah_shortcode]</pre>
```